# Compare two files having different column numbers and print the requirement to a new file if condition satisfies

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have two files with more than 10000 rows:

```
File1 has 1 col      File2 has 4 col     
23                   23 88 90 0
34                   43 74 58 5
43                   54 87 52 3
54                   73 52 35 4 
.                    .
.                    .
```

I want to compare each value in file-1 with that in file-2. If exists then print the value along with other three values in file-2. In this example output will be:

```
 23 88 90 0
 43 74 58 5
 54 87 52 3
 .
 .
```

I have written following script, but it is taking too much time to execute.

```
s1=1; s2=$(wc -l < File1.txt)
while [ $s1 -le $s2 ]
do n=$(awk 'NR=="$s1" {print $1}' File1.txt)
   p1=1; p2=$(wc -l < File2.txt)
   while [ $p1 -le $p2 ]
   do awk '{if ($1==$n) printf ("%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4);}'> ofile.txt
   (( p1++ ))
   done
(( s1++ ))
done
```

Is there any short/ easy way to do it?

Comment: `$s1` won't be expanded because it's inside single quotes. If you want to use a shell variable in an `awk` script, assign it to an `awk` variable with `awk -v s1="$s1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very shortly using `awk` as

```
awk 'FNR==NR{found[$1]++; next} $1 in found'
```

**Test**

```
>>> cat file1
23
34
43
54

>>> cat file2
23 88 90 0
43 74 58 5
54 87 52 3
73 52 35 4

>>> awk 'FNR==NR{found[$1]++; next} $1 in found' file1 file2
23 88 90 0
43 74 58 5
54 87 52 3
```

**What it does?**

- `FNR==NR` Checks if `FNR` file number of record is equal to `NR` total number of records. This will be same only for the first file, `file1` because `FNR` is reset to `1` when awk reads a new file.

  - `{found[$1]++; next}` If the check is true then creates an associative array indexed by `$1`, the first column in `file1`
- `$1 in found` This check is only done for the second file, `file2`. If column 1 value, `$1` is and index in associative array `found` then it prints the entire line ( which is not written because it is the default action)